# Android - Need an activity but don't want an activity?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity, text-to-speech

I am trying to create an app which uses textToSpeak. Apparently textToSpeak has to be used within an activity for it to work.

However I wan't to be able to have textToSpeak in a normal java class so I can instantiate it in the currently running activity and call a method which makes the textToSpeech speak out certain text.

I have managed to get TTS to work when in a separate project and it is the running activity however I cannot get it to instantiate in a a different one...

Speak class (which holds TTS, the problematic line is "private TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);" - provides an uncaught exception.

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class Speech extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    private String toRead;

    public void speak()
    {
        speakOut();
    }

    public void changeText(String changeTo)
    {
        toRead = changeTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {
        tts.speak(toRead, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
```

Running activity( Edited to show how I want to use the speech class)

```
public class Text_entry extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
private Speech speech = new Speech();

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
speech.changeText(toRead);
        speech.speak();
}
}
```

This set up works fine for other objects however because TTS needs to be part of an activity (it is unrecognized if speech does not extend activity) I doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

LogCat

```
02-16 16:52:46.698: D/AndroidRuntime(22541): Shutting down VM
02-16 16:52:46.698: W/dalvikvm(22541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fe300)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.BT/org.BT.Text_entry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TtsEngines.getDefaultEngine(TtsEngines.java:75)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.getDefaultEngine(TextToSpeech.java:1235)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:595)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:553)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:527)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:512)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at org.BT.Speech.<init>(Speech.java:12)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at org.BT.Text_entry.<init>(Text_entry.java:48)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
02-16 16:52:46.703: E/AndroidRuntime(22541):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't extend `Activity`. Pass a `Context` to the constructor instead:

```
public class Speech implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public Speech(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(c, this);
    }

    // Rest of class
}
```

Then construct it like so:

```
public class Text_entry extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    private Speech speech;

    public void onCreate(Bundled saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
        speech = new Speech(this);
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        speech.changeText(toRead);
        speech.speak();
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely has been a step in the right direction. I no longer get any errors and Logcat states I have Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts and connected to TTS service

The only problem now is that there is no sound :(

Comment: @user2052839 Is the phone in USB debugging mode? That can cause no sound to come out. TTS can also take some time to initialize before it is able to speak.

Comment: The coding definitely works on an emulator ... just got to figure out why it isn't on phone. It's not just this that will not work - It is the standalone example where the TTS is in the main activity that will not work on the phone also

Comment: @user2052839 I think, were I you, I'd start a new question regarding the TTS not working (as this question will not bring in people who know TTS well). I'd also take a look around Google to see what can cause that kind of behavior.